# My USB flash drive suddenly get write protected, now I can't format this. how can I do this in Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, gparted, usb-drive, file-format

I have tried GParted in Ubuntu & dosfstools also but it didn't work. Also tried 'ease us' in Windows.
please help me to find a solution using the Ubuntu terminal

Comment: Check that the write-protect slider/switch is on RW. If that is ok, then unmount the drive and run `fsck /dev/drivename`. This will fix filesystem errors. Then remount it.

Comment: no, I don't have a slider in this USB drive.

Comment: @Shibaram Mazumder: Use the flash drive warranty https://kb.sandisk.com/app/rmaform

Answer (score 1):

It's a hardware failure and you can't reverse it through software. It's just that you're not able to format it but the data is intact. If I were you, I would buy a new one. There is no harm in trying different options because it may or may not work. I'm talking from my personal experience as I did many things when I was in such situation but wasted my time.

Comment: I think you are right, it's from the hardware side. I have tried too many things but it didn't work. but it's maybe for a trojan virus that comes in from a software crack.

Comment: @ShibaramMazumder, You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035), and if you are lucky, make it work again. But I agree with Jijo that it is most likely a hardware failure.

Comment: Buy a new one? If you still have the receipts, etc you can return it. The warranty is usually 5 years or so on flash drivesn, What make is it?